# Scraping Data from easports.com, problems with <ea-elements-loader>

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

So i've been working on a Python WebScraper which is crawling a website to find data (e.g wins, loses) from our FIFA ProClub. I've got it working on a third-party website with just BeautifulSoup and requests, but now i am struggling with the [www.ea.com/de-de/games/fifa/fifa-20/pro-clubs/rankings](http://www.ea.com/de-de/games/fifa/fifa-20/pro-clubs/rankings) Site, not only because the table takes some time to load (thought i fixed that by the "wait for element to load"), but also with the sourcecode.
Apparently the code isn't fully displayed when downloading the pure sourcecode, just when i am inspecting the specific element that i want to scrape. I've also noticed that it takes some time to load the code, when i inspect. **I guess part of the problem is the element "ea-elements-loader" which kind of houses the div's i want, but i don't really understand what they did there**.
Basic scraping is not my problem and i know that selenium might be some kind of overkill.

Summed up the main problem is, that when the code is being printed the div class i was looking for is missing, even tough it appears when using the chrome inspect tool.

I am really stuck at this point, code is down below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

DRIVER_PATH = './chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.ea.com/de-de/games/fifa/fifa-20/pro-clubs/rankings")

#edited
time.sleep(5)

print(driver.page_source)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
code_soup = soup.find_all(("div", {"class": "eapl-proclub-table__data"}))
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've tested your code it seems that a timeout exception is raised by the following line:

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'eapl-proclub-table__data')))
```

I've replaced this line with:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

And your code works. It prints out the whole page_source

Comment: Let me know if you wanted a different answer

Comment: Yes i now what you mean, i've also tried this. But if you look in the printed code for the div class i search "eapl-proclub-table__data" u recognize that it's missing, even tought it appears when using the chrome/firefox inspect tool

Comment: Just to clarify. When you try:
print(code_soup)
it prints nothing? Because I tried it and everything was printed normally.

Comment: No, it prints the code, but the printed code is missing the content. It's a bit hard to explain, but e.g i am looking for the name "BARCELONA" but its not showing up in the printed code, even tough in theory it should be the child of a div with the class "eapl-proclub-table__data"

Comment: Ok I gotcha. It seems that for some reason neither bs4 nor selenium can't find the divs contents after the page has loaded. I'm sorry but I don't think I can be of any use further to this problem. I see that this data is loaded from another request by the page but I'm not sure how to access that request with right permissions. I hope you can find your answer.